# How do I return an expression in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a function that takes in a weird argument due to `**kwargs`

```
def create_record_table(Base, table_name, **kwargs):
  class RecordTable(Base):
      __tablename__ = table_name
      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      for key, value in kwargs.items():
          exec("{0} = {1}".format(key,value))
  return RecordTable
```

here is an example of someone calling this function

```
test = create_record_table(Base, "testtable", index="Column(String)")
```

I would like to create a function or a class that creates or return the `index="Column(String)"` part.

for example, a user could do this

```
index = Atomic("col_name", "String")
test = create_record_table(Base, "testtable", index)
```

or similarly:

```
index = Atomic("col_name", "Integer")
test = create_record_table(Base, "testtable", index)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def Atomic(col_name, col_type):
    return {'index': '%s(%s)' % (col_name, col_type)}
```

And then you need to call `create_record_table` like this:

```
kwargs = Atomic('testcol', 'String')
create_record_table(Base, 'testtable', **kwargs)
```

---

If you don't want to add `**` before `kwargs` when calling `create_record_table`, you can change the declaration of `create_record_table` to this:

```
def create_record_table(Base, table_name, kwargs):
```

Now, you can call it just like this:

```
kwargs = Atomic('testcol', 'String')
create_record_table(Base, 'testtable', kwargs)
```

But in this way, it will make the `create_record_table` not compatible with the older code.

Comment: It didnt work.TypeError: create_record_table() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention that you need to change the way you call the `create_record_table`. Add it in my answer.